# How to share between controllers eloquent model data in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

let's assume that I have variables which are used all across page like  currencies and languages. To share them between views I use AppServiceProvider like this:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('currenciesGlobal',Currency::get());
        View::share('languagesGlobal',Language::get());
    }
}
```

I can easily access them in view but I cannot do that in controller. For example I have product list which is calculating price according to currency chosen by user(stored in session as currencyId).

Just for example:

```
public function getPrice()
{
    return number_format($this->price_retail / $this->sessionHelper->getCurrentCurrency()->conversion_rate, 2);
}
```

So 30 products will create 30 queries to currency table. I would like to have a global variable with eloquent collection which I can access in every controller.

I have tried storing data in config files (but there I cannot use eloquent/db); session is rather bad idea.

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: can you please post the data of your eloquent/db which kind of data you want to store or needed from global ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use Inheritance:**

Create a `BaseController` and define your global variables there and make sure all your controllers extend this `BaseController`

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Add global vars, can even use eloquent models here.
     *
    */
    protected $global;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        // Fetch the user object
        $this->global = User::first();
        View::share('global', $this->global);
    }
}
```

Now make sure your other controllers extend this controller and access `$this->global`

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\BaseController;

class OtherController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        // call parent model constructor
        parent::__construct(); 
    }
    // $this->global is available throughout this controller.
    // ...
```

Comment: Additional note:  in child controller I had to add "parent::__construct();" because  BaseController construct was not fired and no variable was set.